# SSRS - grouping with ceiling

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I'm creating a SSRS-report where I need to group my values and do another grouping based on the grouped values. Then I also want to limit the records on each row.

Now my table look like this (but with maybe 50 values):

- A
- A
- A
- B
- C
- C
- D
- E
- E
- F

(ignore the bullets, it was the only way to get the values vertical)
I want my table to fit in one page and become horizontal and be grouped.

The result I'm after look like this:

- A, B, C,
- D, E, F

I writing this in MDX because I need to have data direct from the cube.

I would have a great solution if i didn't have to group the values together.
It's was to use the ceiling-function (`ceiling(rownumber(nothing) mod 6)`) in ColumnGroup and (`=ceiling(rownumber(nothing) / 6)`) in RowGroup.

Has someone a solution, maybe a nested expression to both group the values and then do the ceiling trick?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add a calculated field to the dataset, GroupID,  with a value based on the position in the alphabet and your paging requirement.

For example :

```
Letter   GroupID
A-F      1
G-L      2
M-Q      3
```

Next you can group similar to below.

```
Column Group 1 Expression = GroupID
    Column Group 2 Expression = Letter
```

You may wish to place a page break after group for Group1 to force repeats on a new page.

Comment: This could be an excellent solution, but it can be different many rows depending on which letter the product starts on that's why I can't use this as a solution. It would act like a sting but isn't, it's a vertical table that is grouped (distincted) by productname. Many thanks anyway!